# specify route to IP on unix machine

Tags: router, unix, routing, subnet, static-routes

I have two routers.  Machines on the parent router (10.x.x.x) can't ping machines on the child router (192.168.x.x) .  The parent router doesn't allow static routing.  Can I do something on the command line on the computer itself to be able to ping machines on the 192.x.x.x child network?

Comment: Could you try to use the LAN side port of the child router and not use the WAN port on it at all for the link to the parent router's LAN? This would make it so the child router would be on same subnet as the parent router perhaps LAN to LAN. I think the issue is with getting the ping/ICMP to come back through the WAN side port from the parent router and accessing machines on the local network from the WAN/untrusted interface side on the child router which is like allowing anything from the Internet to access all the machines on your private/trusted network.

Comment: Depending on your setup (which you didn't explain), it may be easier to use the child router as a simple switch, and let the parent router handle DHCP etc. Then all machines on your network will have 10.x.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes – configure the exact same kind of static routing. (That is, use the exact same network and gateway settings as you would have added on the "parent" router.)

The command to temporarily add a route is `ip route add` on Linux; `route add` on BSDs; and a slightly different `route add` on Windows. (Configuring a persistent route varies greatly. Tablet/mobile operating systems usually do not expose routing options at all.)

Make sure that the "child" router's firewall doesn't block incoming connections.

Think about whether you *need* two separate subnets (in many cases, people needlessly stack routers when all they wanted was a 2nd Wi-Fi access point), as pointed out in @TheFurryIT's comment.

Comment: I do.  What command would route traffic to `192.x.x.x` through the router at address `10.0.0.17`?